# Use workflow to automatically create task for insurance renewal invite

Tags: workflow, user, date, workflow-tasks-list

I have a list with contains information on insurance policies, such as "type of insurance", Client name, inception date, expiry date, premium as well as "staff responsible column (which contains the staff member responsible for that particular policy).

I have created a column which auto populates with a date 60 days before the expiry date column date when new data is imputed.

I am trying to create a solution whereby I use the date in the -60day column to trigger a workflow which automatically creates a new task (titled with the policyID, client name +policy type) with a due date of "expiry date" and associated with the staff member in the column on the policy list.

So in summary, how staff member "Steve" can be (automatically) assigned a task of following up with a client 60days before their insurance policy expires.

Many thanks!

M

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the OOTB workflows available. This will create a TASK to the assigned person. Also, you can use set up this in your List with your custom relevant fields.

e.g OOTB Wfs: Collect Feedback WF.
You can use the SP designer to modify the default WF behaviours/parameters.

**STEPS:** 
1. See if OOTB workflow feature is activated for SP site collection? If not just activate this
[image]

2. Activate the WF for your custom List/Library
   [image]

Further, You can modify the OOTB workflow based on your need. I mean, duh... Why  re-invent the wheel. This is a **simple [blog](http://punaro.com/2012/01/derek/modifying-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-email/comment-page-1/)** which shows play around with OOTB Wfs

Hope this helps !